# Set hwclock to UTC on linux

Tags: linux, timezone, centos, clock, reboot

how do i set my hwclock on centos to UTC time permanently.The value changes from UTC to localtime on reboot.This is causing my application to have time drift./etc/sysconfig file UTC value also toggles from true to false after reboot.

Answer (score 5):

Run the command,

```
sudo hwclock --systohc --utc
```

Answer (score 0):

set UTC to true in /etc/sysconfig/clock config file

Comment: I have set the value of /etc/sysconfig/clock file to true. the value changes after reboot